# how do I get my exchange email to notifiy me when my phone is in my holder? HTC DNA

Tags: notifications, email

I only get notification when I have my phone in opened (in my hand unlocked) from my Exchange (work). I need to get the phone to alert me when it is just setting there. Right now I have to open the phone and check, this does not work for after hours support. I have a HTC DNA. Any help would me nice, for me this is a job exposure.

Comment: This will depend on large part what email app you're using.